# Does a statement after defer: get called when breaking iteration early?

Tags: nim-lang

For example when iterating over lines of a file using the lines iterator from the standard library, does the file get closed correctly if I break the iteration early using break?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says:

```
var f = open("numbers.txt")
defer: close(f)
f.write "abc"
f.write "def"
```

Gets translated into:

```
var f = open("numbers.txt")
try:
  f.write "abc"
  f.write "def"
finally:
  close(f)
```

So the `close(f)` will be always called after the `try` code, even if it includes a `break`.